# jenkins pipeline for selenium framework is throwing Error when executing always post condition: java.io.IOException: Truncated TAR archive

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, selenium-grid

I have migrated to selenium 4.8.1 from 3.141.59. My jenkins pipeline was working properly with selnium 3.141.59 but when I migrated to selenium 4.8.1 jenkins pipeline throwing Error when executing always post condition:
`java.io.IOException: Truncated TAR archive

Error when executing always post condition:
java.io.IOException: Truncated TAR archive at
org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveInputStream.read(TarArchiveInputStream.java:743)

```
at java.base/java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:205)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1309)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:978)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1282)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:953)
at hudson.util.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:53)
at hudson.FilePath.readFromTar(FilePath.java:2982)
Also:       Also:   hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from ip-10-26-93-19.ec2.internal/10.26.93.19:36520
at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1784)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:356)
at hudson.remoting.Channel$2.adapt(Channel.java:1034)
at hudson.remoting.Channel$2.adapt(Channel.java:1030)
at hudson.remoting.FutureAdapter.get(FutureAdapter.java:66)
at hudson.FilePath.copyRecursiveTo(FilePath.java:2753)
at jenkins.model.StandardArtifactManager.archive(StandardArtifactManager.java:73)
at hudson.tasks.ArtifactArchiver.perform(ArtifactArchiver.java:256)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:101)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:71)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
java.io.IOException: This archive contains unclosed entries.
at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveOutputStream.finish(TarArchiveOutputStream.java:291)
at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveOutputStream.close(TarArchiveOutputStream.java:309)
at hudson.util.io.TarArchiver.close(TarArchiver.java:125)
at hudson.FilePath.writeToTar(FilePath.java:2953)
at hudson.FilePath.access$3500(FilePath.java:212)
at hudson.FilePath$CopyRecursiveRemoteToLocal.invoke(FilePath.java:2916)
at hudson.FilePath$CopyRecursiveRemoteToLocal.invoke(FilePath.java:2901)
at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:3487)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:376)
at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(InterceptingExecutorService.java:78)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at hudson.remoting.Engine$1.lambda$newThread$0(Engine.java:121)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException
at hudson.remoting.Channel$2.adapt(Channel.java:1036)
at hudson.remoting.Channel$2.adapt(Channel.java:1030)
at hudson.remoting.FutureAdapter.get(FutureAdapter.java:66)
at hudson.FilePath.copyRecursiveTo(FilePath.java:2753)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to extract /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/myworkspace/abc_server_automation_run/transfer of 54 files
at hudson.FilePath.readFromTar(FilePath.java:2992)
at hudson.FilePath.copyRecursiveTo(FilePath.java:2750)
at jenkins.model.StandardArtifactManager.archive(StandardArtifactManager.java:73)
at hudson.tasks.ArtifactArchiver.perform(ArtifactArchiver.java:256)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:101)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:71)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

\[Pipeline\] }
\[Pipeline\] // stage
\[Pipeline\] }
\[Pipeline\] // withEnv
\[Pipeline\] }
\[Pipeline\] // node
\[Pipeline\] }
\[Pipeline\] // podTemplate
\[Pipeline\] End of Pipeline
ERROR: Exit code is non zero, few tests failed so erroring out!
Finished: FAILURE

+ ls -l /tmp/shared/output/
  total 4
  drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Feb 24 11:54 smoke-results
  \[Pipeline\] sh
+ cp -r /tmp/shared/output/ .
  \[Pipeline\] sh
+ ls -alh ./output
  total 4.0K
  drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   27 Feb 24 11:54 .
  drwxr-xr-x 7 1000 1000  283 Feb 24 11:54 ..
  drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4.0K Feb 24 11:54 smoke-results
  \[Pipeline\] archiveArtifacts
  Archiving artifacts
  \[Pipeline\] sh
+ docker-compose down\`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the access permission of below folders/files if it has changed. Ensure they have read/write permission.

```
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to extract /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/myworkspace/abc_server_automation_run/transfer of 54 files
```